# SimpleCV gauge needle angle

Tags: simplecv, gauge

Currently working on a project to read the gauges on our chiller.  I'm not a programmer by trade, so I'm trying to learn as I go, but SimpleCV's documentation isn't that great (IMO...)

At the moment I'm doing a findLines on each image, and it sort of works, but will occasionaly find a "line" on the edge of the gauge itself, or return some other weird result.

What I'd like to do is paint the gauge pivot one color, and the tip of the needle another color, and measure the angle between the two.  I think I have the color blob detection figured out, but I can't figure out the measuring the angle part.

Anyone have any ideas?  All I need is the angle to be returned, the BMS system will accept the angle reading and do the scale conversion itself, so that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

one of the core simplecv developers here.  Sorry the docs aren't up to snuff.

I think if you can paint the gauge it will probably make it easier, or you may not even need to.

I whipped up the example here as you can see image output along the way as well:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/xamox/sandbox/blob/master/gas-gauge-angle/Gauge%20Angle.ipynb

Comment: Looks good to me... I guess I need to do something about the light and gauge reflections, though, as I didn't get any blobs returned when I tried it with my images... http://cable.wilmotnet.com/uplace/PLC/gauges.jpg